# How to delete more then one record in view

Tags: 2007, list-view, delete, bulk

I am trying to delete more then records but I am not sure how, I know in SharePoint 2010 you can edit in datasheet view and easily delete them but how do I do it in 2007? [image]

Comment: Go into datasheet view and delete them, it exists in 2007 too.

Comment: Or link to MS-Access and use a query to delete

Answer (score 1):

1. Click Site Actions, and then click Mange **Content and Structure.**
2. select your list
3. select some items, in actions menu click 'delete'
   [image]

Answer (score -1):

As I remember in 2007 you can do it using datasheet view too. You need to have MS Access installed for it.

Comment: Can you please add some more details about how to do that? To make the answer super helpful

Comment: Unfortunately not, because if I had SP2007 installed, I could attach screenshot, where Access button is, but as I remember on a tool pane in the list should be button with MS Access logo, so when user press it he can switch on datasheet view and delete several items. I'm sorry if that answer is not so full as required, but I just wanted to help.